# Running functional tests for Django on Travis?

Tags: django, selenium

Is it possible to run Selenium tests for Django on Travis? These are my tests:

```
class FrontendTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_homepage(self):
        self.browser.get('http://localhost:8000')
        print self.browser
        assert 'Home' in self.browser.title
```

But obviously, they depend on `localhost` running.

This is the relevant section of my Travis file:

```
script:
 - python manage.py test
 - python frontend/tests/functional_tests.py
```

`manage.py test` runs just fine but the functional tests fail - I guess because localhost isn't up. How can I make sure it is running?

Or should I just not bother running functional tests on Travis?

Comment: You are right, localhost isn't up. Incase you want to run functional tests with travis, use remote webdriver [link](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RemoteWebDriver)

Answer (score 0):

Django's LiveServerTestCase will handle server set up and tear down for you.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/testing/tools/#liveservertestcase